# Using Chinese remainder theorem for Gaussian integers

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem, gaussian-integers

I have the following two questions that am trying to solve.

Use Chinese remainder theorem to solve this system of congruence

1. $x \equiv i \mod (1+i)$ and   $x \equiv 2 \mod 3i$.
2. $x \equiv (−3+i) \mod 5$  and $x \equiv −i \mod (1−i)$.

When I solved it I got $x = -1$ for question 1 and $x = 2 + i$.
But these are wrong. How do I solve this? Any help please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need help in solving the equation above.